# Plotly: How to plot dates on boxplot x-axis?

Tags: python, plotly, boxplot

I am trying to plot a box plot of a dataframe in plotly, dataframe is  as follows:

[image: input dataframe]

I have tried the following:

```py
data = [go.Box(y = Y.iloc[:,i].values) for i, j in enumerate(Y.columns)]
layout = go.Layout(title = 'box plot')
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

I have successfully plotted the desired boxplot,but am not able to plot dates in column headers on X axis of boxplot. Can someone help?

Output is as follows:

[image: Output Image]

Comment: What do you mean with Y.Columns on X Axis plot? You want a rotation or what do you want?

Comment: Does the code shown under https://plotly.com/python/box-plots/#basic-horizontal-box-plot answer your question? If not, maybe rephrase what you actually want to do.

Comment: @SirBaum i want dates mentioned in column headers on X-axis in boxplot.

Comment: Can you provide the any Data to reproduce the boxplot?

Answer (score 0):

To display the dates along the x-axis, you can assign a name for each box plot set to the corresponding date

```
data=[go.Box(y = Y.iloc[:,i].values, name = j) for i,j in enumerate(Y.columns)]
layout = go.Layout(title = 'box plot')
fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure nut I hope this simple trick might work. Firstly perform the `transpose` of the dataframe and then `.reset_index()`and then again `transpose` . This will convert the column headers into your first row and might help you to plot it